# Find all homomophic images of $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Find all homomophic images of $S_3$

I'm studying for a test and came across this question. I know that I will have a queestion on the test asking me to determing the homomorphic image of something. A homomorphism is a mapping from one group to another that preserves the operation.

The answer to the above question is $S_3, \mathbb Z_2,$ and ${e}$ but I don't understand how to get there. What is asking when it wants all homorphic images?

Answer (score 4):

From the first isomorphism theorem any homomorphic image of a group is isomorphic to a quotient of the group by a normal subgroup.

So in the case of $S_3$ we need only find the normal subgroups of $S_3$. You can check that the only normal subgroups are $A_3$, the trivial subgroup, and $S_3$ itself. So any homomorphic image of $S_3$ must be isomorphic to one of $S_3/\{e\} \simeq S_3$, $S_3/A_3\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$, or $S_3/S_3 \simeq \{e\}$.

The general strategy for determining all homomorphic images of a group $G$ is to find all normal subgroups of $G$ and determine the groups obtained by taking the quotient of $G$ by each normal subgroup. By the first isomorphism theorem this gives a complete list of the homomorphic images of $G$ up to isomorphism.

Comment: I'm still very confused. I have a very basic understanding of stuff and am struggling to get all of these definitions and rules memorized. When you say you can check the only normal subgroups, check how?The entire last paragraph confuses me. Can you break that down further?

Comment: In order for it to be a normal subgroups, the left and right cosets have to be the same right?

Comment: The examples [here](http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/normal-subgroups/normal-subgroups.pdf) concerning $S_3$ and the quaternions show how one would go about showing that a concrete subgroup is or is not normal.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking:

> For which groups $G$ is there a surjective homomorphism $\phi: S_3 \to G$ ?

By the first isomorphism theorem, the order of $G$ divides the order of $S_3$, which is $6$, and so can only be $1,2,3,6$. The possible groups $G$ are then $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$, $C_6$, $S_3$.

- $C_1$: take $\phi$ the trivial homomorphism.
- $C_2$: take $\phi$ the sign function.
- $C_3$: cannot happen because every transposition would be taken by $\phi$ to $1 \in C_3$ since $C_3$ has no elements of order $2$. Thus, $\phi$ would be the trivial homomorphism and so not surjective.
- $C_6$: cannot happen because every surjective homomorphism $S_3 \to C_6$ would be injective and so an isomorphism, but $S_3$ is not isomorphic to $C_6$, since $S_3$ is not abelian.
- $S_3$: take $\phi$ the identity function.